# PHP and form action on 1 line

Tags: php, forms, action

I had just asked how to get two 2 form actions on 1 line and someone answered that, but now I want a small line of PHP to be on the same line.

Here's what I have so far:

### PHP

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] )   
    echo "welcome, ".$_SESSION['username'];
```

### HTML

```
<span style="float:right;">
    <form action='logout.php' method='POST'>           
        <input type='submit' value='Logout' />      
    </form>   
</span>
<span style="float:right;">
    <form action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>     
        <input type='submit' value='Change password' />       
    </form>            
</span>
```

You can view the irritation on my website: [www.roundaboutmk.com](http://www.roundaboutmk.com).

You will need to login to see the problem:

- username: `stackoverflow`
- password: `test01`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. I was able to successfully change the password to "test01" and then log out, and log back in using this new password.

Comment: @Shamil, that'd be my fault. The password change thing does work. Try "test01". =P

Comment: lol, this is my problem
you will notice that there is a message on the top right hand side of the page saying "welcome, Stackoverflow" and on the righthand side and on the second line there are two buttons, i want the welcome message and the buttons to be on the same lin

Comment: I would edit it for you, the question, but I don't have edit privileges.

Comment: it is been answered by hans :), thank you for all your help

Comment: This is more CSS related than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you want the php echo also in a span with float right??

just place it before the two buttons

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] )   

    echo "<span style='float:right'>Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."</span>";
```

Comment: have you been to the website and logged in, if so, you will notice that there is a message on the top right hand side of the page saying "welcome, Stackoverflow" and on the righthand side and on the second line there are two buttons, i want the welcome message and the buttons to be on the same line

Comment: the password has been changed to test01

Comment: try use: if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])) instance of if ($_SESSION['username'] )